# mysql LIKE query contains ampersand symbol. How to allow LIKE query for text that contains such symbols?

Tags: mysql, sql-like, stop-words

My search query is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where table1.field LIKE '%P&G Innovation Center%'
```

Note the `&` inside the query.

This does not return me accurate results.

What should I do to get accurate results?

Comment: What does it return that it shouldn't ? It works [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e0d/2). Ampersand is not a [MySQL special character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html). Anyway, as shown in the fiddle, escaping it doesn't seem to harm.

Comment: In what way do the results look wrong? I would have thought that the ampersand would not need escaping the way that a percent sign would. The escape character is a backslash, so if you think it is a problem with ampersand having a special meaning then you could escape it.

Comment: LIKE should work fine with ampersands. This SQLfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1411d/1 ) suggests so too. What's the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you guys! Turns out it was a javascript where I forgot to encode the search query text. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code for ajax search and the normal non-ajax search.

I only check the MySQL query in the non-ajax search.

Turns out the ajax search, I forgot to use `encodeURIComponent` to escape the `&` properly.

Silly me!

Answer: error turns out to be due to missing `encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)` at the javascript instead of MySQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your query
SELECT * FROM table1 where table1.field LIKE '%P&' || 'G Innovation Center%'